# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que los datos ingresados los muestre separados en otro jTextField?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente en este programa de java, jFrame.

Mi inconveniente es que al darle click al botón ingreso de datos de vendedores, al momento de ingresarlos no hay ningún problema pero al querer mostrarlos los datos los muestra en la misma casilla. Es decir todos los nombres ingresados los muestra en la primera casilla de nombre y apellido, todos los artículos vendidos los muestra en la primera casilla de artículos vendidos y así con las otras 2 casillas.

Dejaré todo el código en este enlace:

https://gist.github.com/Chorizo1414/3c350d8f2d4ba0a474cef5a4a02cb38b

Aquí adjunto la imagen del menú

[image: El menú]

Quisiera que se vayan mostrando en los otros espacios (jTextField) y no es la misma casilla.

Esté es el problema que quisiera solucionar

[image: Mostrar los datos en otras casillas]

Están son las variables que utilice de manera global:

```
    String Vendedores, nombre;
    int vendedores;
    int ventas;
    int sueldo;
    double sueldoF;
```

Aquí está el código del Botón, el cual nos sirve para el ingreso de los datos y de las operaciones que debe hacer.

```
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
        int i;

        do
        {
            Vendedores = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese la cantidad de vendedores");
            vendedores = Integer.parseInt(Vendedores);
            
            
            if(vendedores >= 3 && vendedores <= 8)
            {
                for( i = 0;  i < vendedores; i++)
                {
                    nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese el nombre y apellido del vendedor");
                    jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+nombre);
        
                    String Ventas = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese la cantidad de articulos vendidos");
                    ventas = Integer.parseInt(Ventas);
                    jTextField9.setText(jTextField9.getText()+ventas);
        
                    if(ventas >= 100 && ventas <= 300)
                    {
                        sueldo = ventas * 125;
                        jTextField17.setText(jTextField17.getText()+sueldo);
            
                        sueldoF = sueldo * 0.1067;
                        jTextField25.setText(jTextField25.getText()+sueldoF);
                    }
        
        
                    else if(ventas >= 301 && ventas <= 500) 
                    {
                        sueldo = ventas * 145;
                        jTextField17.setText(jTextField17.getText()+sueldo);
            
                        sueldoF = sueldo * 0.1067;
                        jTextField25.setText(jTextField25.getText()+sueldoF);
            
                    }
        
        
                    else if(ventas >= 501 && ventas <= 800) 
                    {

                        sueldo = ventas * 165;
                        jTextField17.setText(jTextField17.getText()+sueldo);
            
                        sueldoF = sueldo * 0.1067;
                        jTextField25.setText(jTextField25.getText()+sueldoF);
            
                    }
        
        
                    else if(ventas >= 801 && ventas <= 1000) 
                    {
                        sueldo = ventas * 175;
                        jTextField17.setText(jTextField17.getText()+sueldo);

                        sueldoF = sueldo * 0.1067;
                        jTextField25.setText(jTextField25.getText()+sueldoF);
            
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        jTextField9.setText("");
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ingrese una cantidad mayor que 100 o menor que 10001");
                    }
                    
                    
                }//cierra for
        
            }
        
            else 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ingrese una cantidad de 3 a 8 vendedores");
            }
            
        }while(vendedores <=3 || vendedores >=8); 
    }
```

Comment: tu codigo parece incompleto, trata de tener siempre un [mcve]

Comment: facil el campo 2º tiene el mismo nombre del primero seguro y x eso te salen lo datos asi tendria que ver todo el codigo pero debe ser algo del estilo. Si pones todo el codigo te lo miro

Comment: Aquí está todo el código:

https://gist.github.com/Chorizo1414/3c350d8f2d4ba0a474cef5a4a02cb38b

Comment: ¿Por qué haces esto: `jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+nombre);`?

Comment: para que el nombre se vaya y se muestre en ese jTextField1.

Comment: Siempre en jTextField1 ¿dónde está ubicado?. ¿Para qué usas `.getText()`?